# HACK Machines and its assembler

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

couldn't really get much information about the virtual register. 
All i know is the R0 to R15 which is address 0 to 15 are pre-defined.

Is virtual register = virtual machine?
so what is a virtual register in the context of Hack machine and its assembler?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you are referring to? "HACK machine" is a bit too generic to search for. If you're referring to hack as in HAKMEM then they are targeting the PDP-10 architecture, with R0-R15 being 36-bit hardware registers mapped at the base of the address space.

Comment: Im talking about The Hack computer, von Neumann platform. It is a 16-bit machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've have never heard of HACK machine before, so I looked for it on Google and found the official page, read a couple of PDFs and make a simple test. All this just to say: I have 5 min preparation on this subject :)

Virtual Register are just **symbols**, names for numbers. `R2` is just another way to write `2`.

[image: Assembled @R2 and @2 instructions]

The manual states

> To simplify assembly programming, the symbols R0 to R15 are
>   predefined to refer to RAM addresses 0 to 15, respectively.

I initially thought you could use them like this `R3=D-1` or even `R3=R2+R3`. In the HACK machine accessing memory is very verbose as you can only address it indirectly by the use of the `A` register, so I thought that Virtual Registers could be used to automatically generate more complex code, say by assembling `R3=R1+R2` into

`@1
D=M
@2
D=D+M
@3
M=D`

But this is not the case, you can use them only with the `@` instruction and I don't see how this would simplify assembly.

They can make it more **readable** if you stick to the convention that memory locations are loaded into `A` only by using labels, so that if you see a `@R10` you known/expect that `A` is loaded with an address and when you see an (equivalent) `@10` you know/expect that `A` contains a values for arithmetic computation (say adding 10 to `D`).
This is just pure semantic however, a matter of how you use the assembler, like naming string variable with *str* prefix, and have not meaning to the assembler itself.